# How do I permit! with strong parameters in rails 4?

Tags: strong-parameters

I am having issues permitting all on one of the sub-hashes. How could I do this in strong_params in Rails 4?

```
    params.require(:checkout_item).permit(:checkout_group_transaction_id, :item_type, :property_id,
                                          :image)
    params.require(:checkout_item[:data]).permit!
```

Where :checkout_item[:data] should be permit all ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is whitelist every key in `params[:checkout_item][:data]`, which is a hash. You can use the `keys` method here to return an array of the keys for that hash.

```
params.require(:checkout_item).permit(:checkout_group_transaction_id, 
                                      :item_type, :property_id, :image,
                                      {:data => params[:checkout_item][:data].try(:keys)})
```

Now every key in `params[:checkout_item][:data]` will be permitted regardless of how many keys appear for a given request. Note the use of `try` to avoid raising a `NoMethodError` exception on `params[:checkout_item][:data]` in the event that it is `nil` since you may not need to pass the `:data` sub hash on every request to create or update.

I took this idea from the [action controller rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) section 4.5.4 *Outside the Scope of Strong Parameters*.

Hope this helps!